# How to use wildcard for document.getElementsByName?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am trying to do a very simple thing that is filling an input box using javascript bookmarklet in Firefox.

Here is the snippet of related code and screenshot:

[image]

```
<input id="T22401715851381308556344_j_id_id0:freeSMSBean:receiverNumber" class="text" type="text" style="POSITION: absolute;" onblur="validateReceiverNumber(this,'');" maxlength="10" value="" name="T22401715851381308556344_j_id_id0:freeSMSBean:receiverNumber"></input>
```

I can fill in the value using the following javascript bookmarklet:

```
javascript:{document.getElementsByName('T22401715851381308556344_j_id_id0:freeSMSBean:receiverNumber')[0].value='1234';void(0)}
```

However the problem is that the **bold** part of name keeps changing.
**T22401715851381308556344_j_id_id0**:freeSMSBean:receiverNumber

I would like to know can I somehow match the changing part using a wildcard. or is there a better solution for filling in this input box?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`$=` selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings) with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
document.querySelectorAll("[name$=\":freeSMSBean:receiverNumber\"]");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/869p6knz/

---

`querySelectorAll` is a method of `document` and `Element` which lets you search for elements with valid CSS selectors.

[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) is also available if you would only want the first result.

Comment: I could not get querySelector to work. Any idea why? (mind you I don't know anything about programming).   javascript:{document.querySelector("[name$=\":freeSMSBean:receiverNumber\"]")[0].value='1234';void(0)}

Comment: @Ballanne Why are the statements inside a `{}`?

Comment: I don't know. It was from another bookmarklet that I copied and altered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this using `document.getElementsByName` but you can do this using `document.querySelector` like this:

```
var textbox = document.querySelector('input[type="text"][name$=":freeSMSBean:receiverNumber"]');
// do whatever you wanna do with textbox
```

If you wanna get all the textboxes whose name attribute ends with `:freeSMSBean:receiverNumber`, you can use `document.querySelectorAll` instead.

```
var textboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"][name=":freeSMSBean:receiverNumber"]');
```